# #Unity3D - How to attach an object to another using a face of the last object as a target

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I would like to know if it is possible to use the face of an object (for example let's name it Object 1) and use the face as a target to position another object (Object 2) side by side, using the face of Object 2 as the second target.

Let's say that I have three simple box-like objects and I want to make different compositions by adding to the first object, already present in the scene, another one and then the other in whatever order i want by pressing a specific key on the keyboard (let's say W key for the Object 2 and S key for the Object 3).

It doesn't need to be with this method that I thought, but it needs to be the same process.
It should take into consideration the size of the object and also the rotation.

[image: Image For Reference]

Comment: Have you tried to create a script to transform the desired objects? Do you have some restriction to how retrieve the objects information? If not you could simply use some [`transform()`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.html)

Comment: No problem, I was trying to get more info, but [@Voidsay in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74561549/10301322) already show what I was thinking

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible solution is to carfully make prefabs of your shapes in a way that would allow you to instantiate them so that they are aligned correctly.

The following overview shows your three shapes saved as prefabs. They have been constructed using an `Empty GameObject` (blue diamond) and attaching the 3d model (works for sprites as well) and placing another `Empty GameObject` (red diamond) that is rotated so that the green axis arrow points in  the direction of the normal.
[image: overview of the prefabs required]

If you attach the following script to the red diamond `Empty GameObject` and put the prefabs in their slots, you will be able to instantiate shapes 2 and 3 by pressing `S` and `W` respectively.

```csharp
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Placement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject shape1, shape2, shape3;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.W))
        {
            Instantiate(shape3, transform.position, transform.rotation);
            this.enabled = false;
        }
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.S))
        {
            Instantiate(shape2, transform.position, transform.rotation);
            this.enabled = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Note that the script also disables itself upon a successful instantiation, so that it only spawns shapes at the very end.